# Tkinter: why is <KeyRelease> less precise than <KeyPress>?

Tags: python, tkinter, events

In my Tkinter program, I need to capture all button presses in an Entry Widget. This is the general idea for the Entry Widget (where printing will be replaced by a more useful function in the final implementation):

```
class QuickSearchBox(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.var = tk.StringVar()
        self.config(textvariable=self.var)
        self.bind('<KeyPress>', lambda e: print(self.var.get()))
```

Now I've noticed that, when typing quickly, `<KeyPress>` captures all key presses (except for the last one), while `<KeyRelease>` doesn't. (I'm running my script from PyCharm on a Windows 10 machine).

As an example, buttonmashing `skjdfhkdjfh` with `<KeyPress>` prints:

```
s
sk
skj
skjd
skjdf
skjdfh
skjdfhk
skjdfhkd
skjdfhkdj
skjdfhkdjf
```

While buttonmashing `sjkdfsdkjf` with `<KeyRelease>` prints:

```
sjkd
sjkdf
sjkdf
sjkdf
sjkdfsdk
sjkdfsdkjf
sjkdfsdkjf
sjkdfsdkjf
sjkdfsdkjf
sjkdfsdkjf
```

I have two questions about this:

- What would explain the difference in behaviour described above?
- Is it possible to have the precision of `<KeyPress>` when it comes to capturing all keypresses, while **also** capturing the last keypress (which only seems to be possible with `<KeyRelease>`)?

Comment: It is not less "precise"(accurate will be the correct word), because you actually released a key while holding multiple keys. Print the ```e.keysym``` at the event handler. I guess you said only a few parts of the problem. Elaborate the whole problem you want to solve.